# Calling main program functions from a dynamically loaded library (QPluginLoader)

Tags: c++, qt, dllimport, symbols

I am loading plugins (DLLs) dynamically at runtime using the Qt *QPluginLoader* class.

So far, I have successfully loaded plugins with functions that are called from the main program. Now, the plugins will need to call other functions in the main program. I've included the relevant header files in the plugin project, and it compiles without errors.

When I try to call the following plugin function from the main program:

```
// main program calling a function in a dll that has been dynamically
// loaded into the program:
PluginInterface* plugin = qobject_cast<PluginInterface*>(QPluginLoader(path)).instance();
plugin->DoSomething(); // works, writes a message to the console
plugin->callMainProgramFunction(); // not working
```

'

```
// test method in the plugin project (dll) that writes to console:
void TestDLL::DoSomething();
{
   std::cout << "Hello, this messages comes from TestDLL! Have a nice day"; // works
}
```

'

```
// test method in the plugin project (dll) that tries to 
// call a method in the main program: 
void TestDLL::callMainProgramFunction()
{  
    Angle test; // angle.h is included, and offers geometric functions
    std::cout << test.sine() << "\n"; // does not work, program stops
}
```

the program stops. I believe this is because the plugin does not know where to find the symbols (the code from *angle.cpp* that is linked and compiled into the main program), since it is linked into the program dynamically afterwards.

Many plugins will use the same functions, therefore I consider compiling each plugin with all the implementations a bad idea.

Is there a solution to this, using *QPluginLoader*? How can I tell the dynamically loaded plugins where to find symbols in the main program? I know that *QLibrary* offers a more manual way of exporting/importing functions and "resolve symbols", but lacks the neat instance functionality of *QPluginLoader*.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dll with common functions that are shared between the plugin and the main program, and link it in both the main program and the plugin.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little? 

Do you mean that I should create a common-functions-dll that is loaded into both the main program and in the plugin? 

Or do you mean that all the common functions should be placed in the dll, so that they are accessible for both? There are many plugins that will use the same functions. 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You know that a dll can be loaded in memory once and shared among different processes, so it can be shared among different "components" of a single process.

So, in your case your app mainapp.exe has a dependency of commfunc.dll, so also your plugin.dll.

When mainapp.exe start, loads in memory commfunc.dll, so all it's functions can be used from plugin.dll because their addresses now can be accessed.

This can not be achieved if the required functions are in the mainapp.exe address space.

Answer (score 0):

**QPluginLoader** solves the problem that I described: Libraries that are loaded dynamically into the main program through *QPluginLoader*, will be able to call functions in the main program.

The cause to my problem was a subtle error in the plugin interface that I use.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but don't forget on Linux to link the main program with the `-rdynamic` flag, so that symbols of the main program are visible from plugins.